# Sort QUERY results to the 4th character of a string

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, regex, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to pull a list of people based on their last names. The catch is I only want to QUERY people with last names that fit between an alpha range to the 4th character.

**Example**

I only want names that fall between `Mimz and Sand`

I have this formula, but it doesn't go to the 4th character and I don't understand how to update.

```
=QUERY(data!B1:J30000, "Select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J  where lower(D) matches 
'^(m[k-z]|[n-r]|sa).*' order by D")
```

I believe the adjustment needs to be made here `(m[k-z]|[n-r]|sa)` but I don't know the syntax.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Link to copy of report tab**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rL0ufamiMfC6qZhalsPw9s0SuKuBdXuNGVx_JtoOSEc/edit#gid=1728510345

**Link to copy of data tab** (simplified)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rL0ufamiMfC6qZhalsPw9s0SuKuBdXuNGVx_JtoOSEc/edit#gid=2033321539

Comment: Please provide some sample data to test your formula and those to be proposed.

Comment: @Rubén I've added the links to the question. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: The spreadsheet looks very complex. Please make a simpler demo spreadsheet.

Comment: @Rubén I've updated link to the "data" sheet and simplified it. I've also removed all other tabs that aren't directly related to this question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is more a regular expression logic update, I can contribute:

Try:

```
'^(mimz|mi[n-z]|m[j-z]|[n-r]|sa[a-m]|san[a-d]).*'
```

Just keep in mind that the range above needs to differ by the first character.  If not, then pull the common characters out.  For mimz-mitz:

```
'^mi(mz|[n-s]|t[a-z]).*'
```

Not saying there isn't an easier way -- this just helps you update this particular way in the future.

Comment: I'm testing this now. Thank you! Is there an easier (more straight forward) way that you recommend?

Comment: First, I don't know how 'dynamic' it needs to be -- this regex is obviously hardcoded.  Second, I don't know excel or its myriad of functions.  So even if this works (and it should ;) ), someone else might come up with a better answer.  That's all I meant.  So short answer -- I don't know ;)